# bash alias for screen command isn't working

Tags: bash, alias

i have couple of `screen` session consistently open in the shell. Each session corresponds to a specific machine/application.

Normally, when i log into my shell, i first do `screen -ls` and then `screen -x <session_id>`.

what i want to do is create `screen -x <session_id>` an alias. well `screen -x 25530` to be precise.

I wrote following command in `~/.zshrc`

```
# SCREEN SESSIONS
screen-prod-appname-eu="screen -x 25530"
```

when i do `source ~/.zshrc`, i get an error that says `command not found: screen-prod-appname-eu=screen -x 25530`

any suggestions?

Comment: Zsh or Bash? You say `~/.zshrc`, but tag "bash".

Comment: Aliases in zsh have the syntax `alias aliasName=aliasValue`. If `aliasValue` contains spaces then use quotes. So use this for your alias: `alias screen-prod-appname-eu='screen -x 25530'`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with system generated session ids is that they keep changing. Thankfully, you can use names to name sessions. Here is what I do:

In my .bashrc I have the following:

```
alias scr='screen -D -R '
```

When I first connect to a system I do

```
$ scr hello
```

If the *hello* session exists it will reconnect to it, otherwise it will create a new one called *hello*. (*hello* is an example name, you can have as many names that make sense to your sessions as you like.)

```
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        52195.hello     (Attached)
```